# this.value is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, class, variables

Class:

```
class decrypt implements Runnable {

    String name = "decode";
    String text;
    Thread t;
    boolean ok = true;
    boolean done = false;

     decrypt(String en) {
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("Thread " + t.getName() + " Started!");
        this.text = en;
    }

    decrypt() {

        t = new Thread(this, "Main");
    }
   void ok(){
       this.ok=true;
    }


    synchronized public void run() {
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String p=input.next();
            String fs = text.replace(p, "").trim();
            System.out.println("Decrypting in progress.....");
            t.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Original  form of '" + text + "' is :'" + fs + "'");
            ok();
            System.out.println("");
            done=true;

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("I handled an error for you, don't worry!");
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

..........

```
 decrypt mm=new decrypt();
                String sd="";
                int itmessss=0;
                while (!sd.equals("0") ){
                    if(mm.ok) { // at first time true, then always false!!
                            mm.t = new Thread(new decrypt(sd));
                            System.out.println("Please wait...");
                            mm.t.start();
}
}
```

..........

Why

```
void ok(){
       this.ok=true;
    }
```

this doesn't set `mm.ok` to `true`, Its at first true then always false!!!

I also tried this:

```
   System.out.println("Original  form of '" + text + "' is :'" + fs + "'");
                this.ok=true;
                System.out.println("");
                done=true;
```

I don't know why this doesn't work, the caller (thread) always reads it as False

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Mark `ok` as `volatile`. `ok` is evaluated only once otherwise.

You are accessing `ok` from two threads.

For an explanation of `volatile` see e.g.:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

I just read your question again. From what I guessed your code should do, you do not need two threads. The `Decrypt` class implements `Runnable`. You can create a thread from your `Decrypt` object then.

This is how I could imagine your code could look like:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Decrypt implements Runnable {
    private String text;
    volatile boolean ok = true;
    boolean done = false;

    public boolean isOk() {
        return this.ok;
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        try {
            final Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            final String p = input.next();
            final String fs = text.replace(p, "").trim();
            System.out.println("Decrypting in progress.....");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Original  form of '" + text + "' is :'" + fs + "'");
            ok = true;
            System.out.println("");
            done = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I handled an error for you, don't worry!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Decrypt mm = new Decrypt();
        String sd = "";
        while (!sd.equals("0")) {
            if (mm.isOk()) { // ok is private to Decrypt class, thus access by method
                final Thread t = new Thread(mm); // You only need one Thread
                System.out.println("Please wait...");
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please exaplain, i am new to Java. What and where do i have to do this?

Comment: Declare your variable ok as volatile boolean ok = true;. The compiler and VM otherwise optimize access to ok. It is "cached" if not declared as volatile.

Comment: Please read my edited post again. A more detailed comment then `Doesn't work!' would be helpful then.

Comment: But this line: ` final String fs = text.replace(p, "").trim();` is returning error `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.book.ch5.decrypt.run(Main.java:609)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)` Else is ok

Comment: So text is null. Do you need it? Then set it before starting the thread. I don't know what your code should do. My code was a guess about the threading issue you asked.